# Dcount function using parameters

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to prevent sql injection in my dcount function which I have here

```
DCount("[Treasury Name]", "tblTreasuries", "[Treasury Name] = '" & txtTreasuryName & "'")
```

this txtTreasuryName is a form input I have , of course the problem is when I input ' or " in the form i get an error and i don't know the right way to make this statement parametric

Comment: Domain aggregate functions are not SQL statements so why is SQL injection a concern? Also, why not a combobox for treasury name value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why a `"` in `txtTreasuryName` would break your `DCount()` expression , but it's clear that a `'` would.

Nevertheless you can avoid problems from either type of quote character by using a reference to the textbox instead of concatenating the textbox's value into your `DCount()` expression.

```vb
DCount("*", "tblTreasuries", "[Treasury Name] = Forms!YourFormName!txtTreasuryName")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can enter `"Name1","Name2"`, then use `IN`:

```
Textbox holds: "Name1","Name2"

Count = DCount("*", "tblTreasuries", "[Treasury Name] In (" & Me!txtInput.Value & ")")
```